# Override HTTP server's mime types?

Tags: html, css, webserver, mime-types

---

**Background**

I'm working with a device (Graphite HMI by RedLion) that has a built in web server that allows me to host a custom web page, which is great, but there is a catch. The web server is very limited as far as which mime types it supports, and it assumes everything that is not of a supported mime type should be text/html. This is horrible because I can't link in css style sheets, link to pdf files, etc. I can live with putting my css in my html files, but the pdf handling is a killer, as I want to host a manual for the software I'm running on the device on it's web server without external links in case it is deployed in a location where there is no internet access.

---

**Question**

So, is there any way I can over-ride/ignore the reported mime type in my "a" tags, and when linking a style sheet?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have tried adding the "type" property to my "a" tags, but most browsers honor the server's mime type over the "a" tag's "type" property.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

The only place you can override the MIME type client side is in an XMLHttpRequest object (which doesn't apply to your situation).

---

> but most browsers honor the server's mime type over the "a" tag's "type" property

This is required by [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-type):

> It is purely advisory. The value must be a valid MIME type. User agents must not consider the type attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use metadata included in the link to the resource to determine its type.

It is there so that, for example, bots can decide not to follow a link (because it points to content they don't index).

Comment: Is there any way I can return the raw file contents with javascript and set the mime type to pdf?, ie: something like this

`function fixPDFMime(path){$.get(path, function( data ){ console.log(typeof data); window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(data)); }); }`

Comment: This half way works as is, I end up with a blank (it shouldn't be blank) 2-page pdf document.